# Netty Socketio SSL

Tags: java, javascript, ssl, netty, socket.io

I cant seem to get the sslchatlauncher from netty socketio [demo](https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio-demo)

I already did this to my server

```
    config.setHostname("localhost");
    config.setPort(9092);
    config.setKeyStorePassword("password");
    InputStream stream = new FileInputStream("C:/keystore.jks");
    config.setKeyStore(stream);
```

While on the javascript client

```
var socket =  io.connect('https://localhost:9092',{secure: true});
```

Still, the client can't connect to the server. Is there any item i am missing?thanks.

Comment: Do you see any errors in browser console?

Comment: no, this is the console  [main] INFO com.corundumstudio.socketio.SocketIOServer - Session store / pubsub factory used: MemoryStoreFactory (local session store only)
[main] INFO com.corundumstudio.socketio.SocketIOServer - SocketIO server started at port: 9092

Comment: @NikitaKoksharov is there any idea i am missing? i also tried running the demo using (mvn exec:java -Dmain.class=com.corundumstudio.socketio.demo.SslChatLauncher) but the client still didnt connect.

Comment: solved. something was blocking/pop up was showing,after that it is now accessible.

Comment: can you please explain how you created the keystore.jks or share a link, because I am also stuck in configuring netty for ssl ...

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. My JKS keystore is working fine on Jetty but not in netty-socket-io. I've been trying almost everything now. @NikitaKoksharov is there documentation how the jks needs to be created so that it works?

Comment: @sensitive_piece_of_horseflesh  you can use this command to generate jks file

`keytool -genkey -alias test -keyalg RSA -keystore test.jks -keysize 3072`